# Simple query return result in ELSE block instead in IF

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Excuse me for the "newbie" question but I have a problem with simple pdo query. What I have is query from two tables and based on user_id to show all his uploaded images. Here is the code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_images      
        LEFT JOIN users 
        ON user_images.user_id = users.id
        WHERE user_images.user_id=:user_id";
$stmt = $db_con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $_SESSION['user']['id']);      
$stmt->execute();
$user_photos = $stmt->fetch();

if (is_object($user_photos) && !empty($user_photos) && $user_photos->num_rows > 0) {
     while ($row = $user_photos->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
          <img src="uploads/<?php echo $row->images_name; ?>"> 
     <?php }} else { ?>
     <li style="text-align: center">
           No Images Found!
     </li>
<?php } ?>
```

What is happening here is that in `IF`  block the image didn't showed. Instead if I do `var_dump($row->images_name);` in `ELSE` block the image is visible.

Comment: Use:- `if ($user_photos->num_rows > 0) {`  only.That is sufficient

Comment: This return `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Why so many downvotes? Please explain because I'm not expert like you..

Comment: i din't down-voted. So how can i tell?

Comment: this is absurd : because you're saying both `If` and `else` are executed simultaneously

Comment: didn't downvote

Comment: I don't refer you Alive but other who are downvoted. User why they executed at the same time?

Comment: Because isn't initialized outside the `If` part, and you said that your `vardump` is in the `else` part, so both are executed

Comment: Yes, I saw this. Silly mistake but still after I moved it outside the `If` part still doesn't show any images in while

Comment: May be path problem.try to provide full path/absolute-path like `<img src="http://your project/uploads/<?php echo $row->images_name; ?>">`

Comment: Nothing. It doesn't even enter in `if` and going straight to `else`, `var_dump($row['images_name']);` return `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_images      
        LEFT JOIN users 
        ON user_images.user_id = users.id
        WHERE user_images.user_id = ?";
$stmt = $db_con->prepare($sql);     
if ($stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user']['id']))) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        echo '<img src="uploads/', $row['images_name'], '">'; 
    }
}
if (empty($row)) { ?>
     <li style="text-align: center">
           No Images Found!
     </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, It's working great tough I still don't know what was the problem

Comment: You were getting the return of `$stmt->fetch();` and used another function to fetch that result. whatever happened after that had to be funny.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with php function `count()`.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_images      
        LEFT JOIN users 
        ON user_images.user_id = users.id
        WHERE user_images.user_id=:user_id";
$stmt = $db_con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $_SESSION['user']['id']);      
$stmt->execute();
$user_photos = $stmt->fetchAll();

if (count($user_photos) > 0) {        
     foreach ($user_photos as $row) {
         echo '<img src="uploads/'.$row['images_name'].'">';
     } 
} else {
      echo '<li style="text-align: center">No Images Found!</li>';
}
```